# How to get data from controller to Factory in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am   newbie to  Angularjs World. I  want  to  fetch  some  data  from angularjs controller to  Angularjs Factory.Controller and factory  are  defined in different js files.

code from  Factory(File  name Application.js)

```
  var app=angular.module('myApp',[])

 app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function(MyController) {
    return {
       getSource: function() {
        return  MyController.getFirstName();

      }
   }
```

}]);

```
 app.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        $(elem).autocompleteArray(autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), {
        minLength: 2
      });
     }

  }})
```

Controller code (File Name Controller.js)

```
  function  MyController($scope){
    this.getFirstName= function ()
  {
      var arrayFName=[];
      for(var k=0;k< $scope.MyData.length;k++)
          {
            arrayFName.push($scope.MyData[k].fname);
          }
     return arrayFName;
  }
```

MyData is array  containing some  hard  coded  value for 'fname'

When  i ran this code  got error 'Error: MyController is undefined'. Is it  possible to   fetch  data  from  controller if   yes   then how?

Comment: You don't want to fetch data from a controller, you want to fetch data from the service to the controller.  Also you should define your controller on the Angular module: `app.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){ ... }])`

Answer (score 1):

You should have source, or `firstName`, defined in the factory, and then set it from the controller.  It will then be accessible from other controllers which use the factory.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])

app.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function () {
    var _source;
    return {
        getSource: function () {
            return _source;
        },
        setSource: function (source) {
            _source = source;
        }
    }
}]);
```

And then subsequent controllers might be like:

```
app.controller('someController', ['$scope', 'autoCompleteDataService',
    function ($scope, autoCompleteDataService) {
        $scope.source = autoCompleteDataService.getSource();

        // or even...
        // $scope.getFirstName = autoCompleteDataService.getSource;
    }]);
```

Comment: The way you're set up, you're trying to call `getSource` in your service, which in turn calls `getFirstName` from your controller.  What you should do, in that controller, is `setSource()` (or `setFirstName`, which would make more sense).  Now, any subsequent requests won't call to the controller (`MyController.getFirstName()`) but to the service (`autoCompleteDataService.getSource()`)

Comment: ...what's not working? Did you make a `setSource` function, and call it from the controller, so that `_source` is set to the object you want to get in `autoCompleteDataService`?